# Where to create business logic objects and maintain state?

Tags: android

My application relies on a core module of Android independent classes to carry out business logic. These objects need to be available to all parts of the app and also needs to maintain its state throughout the application.

I have been instantiating these objects in an Application subclass and using them throughout my activities and services. But when Android decides to kill my app to free up memory, those business logic objects are also killed and lose their state.

What is the best strategy for stateful business object models in an Android application?

Comment: Create a class and serialize it and save to shared preferences or any other android provided storage options.

Comment: Its better you extract all the attributes from your critical objects and dump them to persistant storage such as "SharedPreferences" in android, next time when your application restarts just , re initiate your object from those values.

Comment: Do keep in mind that in `SharedPreferences` you can only store primitives like 'boolean, float, int, long, String' values.

Comment: @Mayank Yes, but you can store a serialised object, assuming that all of it's fields are serialisable.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect solution for this is to use persistence storage. What I follow is bit complex but very useful. 
It is divided in three parts :

1. SQLite Database
2. API Helper
3. Singleton Class ( Data Helper )

and following steps :

1. Retrieve all data from db to single instance classes.
2. Whenever I need to update it then update in class.
3. Dump it in database at some particular event. (like button click or back press).

By this way you have all of your data intact and easily available through out the app

1. **Database** : Not going to elaborate it. It can be any persistence storage like db or preference.
2. **API Helper** : Sample api helper class. It can be any thing depending on your storage.

   ```
   public class AppsApi {    
   private static AppsApi appInstance;
   private Context mContext;

   public static AppsApi getInstance(Context context) {

       if (appInstance == null)
           appInstance = new AppsApi(context);
       return appInstance;

   }

   public AppsApi(Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
   }

   public static String PROJECTION[];

   static {
       String[] arrayOfString = new String[5];
       arrayOfString[0] = AppsTable.COLUMN_ID;
       arrayOfString[1] = AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME;
       arrayOfString[2] = AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME;
       arrayOfString[3] = AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME;
       arrayOfString[4] = AppsTable.COLUMN_IS_FROM_DASHBOARD;
       PROJECTION = arrayOfString;
   }

   public int insertApp(ContentValues app) {

       Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, app);
       System.out.println("APP Added URI :: " + uri);
       return Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());

   }

   public Cursor getAllApps() {
       return mContext.getContentResolver().query(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, AppsApi.PROJECTION,
               null, null, null);
   }

   public Cursor getAllApp(boolean isFromDashBoard) {
       int is = isFromDashBoard ? 1 : 0;
       return mContext.getContentResolver().query(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, AppsApi.PROJECTION,
               AppsTable.COLUMN_IS_FROM_DASHBOARD + " LIKE ?",
               new String[] { is + "" }, null);
   }

   public void deleteApp(int id) {
       mContext.getContentResolver().delete(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP,
               AppsTable.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" });
   }

   public void deleteApp(String packageName) {
       mContext.getContentResolver().delete(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP,
               AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME + " LIKE ?",
               new String[] { packageName + "" });
   }

   public void updateApp(ContentValues app, int id) {
       int uri = mContext.getContentResolver().update(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, app, "_id=?",
               new String[] { id + "" });
       System.out.println("App Updated URI ::" + uri);
   }

   public void clear() {
       mContext.getContentResolver().delete(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, null, null);
   }

   public int count() {
       return ((Cursor) mContext.getContentResolver().query(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP,
               new String[] { AppsTable.COLUMN_ID }, null, null, null))
               .getCount();
   }

   public Cursor filterApp(String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

       return mContext.getContentResolver().query(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, AppsApi.PROJECTION,
               selection, selectionArgs, null);
   }

   public int insertBulkApps(ContentValues[] apps) {

       int noOfRecordInserted = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(
               DashDroidContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_APP, apps);
       System.out.println("Inserted Record Count :: " + noOfRecordInserted);
       return noOfRecordInserted;

   }
   ```

   }
3. **Data Helper** : It is a single instance class. Provides you with data through out the app. It is huge but simple.

   ```
   public class AppsHelper {

   public static final int TYPE_SAVE = 0;
   public static final int TYPE_GET = 1;
   public static final int TYPE_UPDATE = 2;

   private AppsData[] appsDashBoard;
   private AppsData[] appsMoreApps;

   private AppsApi appsProvider;

   private OnDataBaseUpdateListener mListener;

   private static AppsHelper mHelper;

   public AppsHelper(Context context) {
       appsProvider = AppsApi.getInstance(context);
       initData();
       if (appsProvider.count() == 0) {
           new saveDataTask().execute();
       } else {
           updateAppsFromDatabase();
       }

   }

   public static AppsHelper getInstance(Context context) {

       if (mHelper == null)
           mHelper = new AppsHelper(context);

       return mHelper;

   }

   private void initData() {

       appsDashBoard = new AppsData[DashDroidConstants.NO_OF_DASH_BOARD_APPS];
       appsMoreApps = new AppsData[DashDroidConstants.NO_OF_MORE_APPS];

       for (int i = 0; i < appsDashBoard.length; i++) {
           appsDashBoard[i] = new AppsData(i, "null", "null", "null");
       }

       for (int i = appsDashBoard.length; i < (appsMoreApps.length + appsDashBoard.length); i++) {
           appsMoreApps[i - appsDashBoard.length] = new AppsData(i, "null",
                   "null", "null");
       }

   }

   public void updateMoreApp(String appName, String activityName,
           String appPackageName, int index) {
       appsMoreApps[index].setData(appName, activityName, appPackageName);
       new updateDataTask(false, index).execute();
   }

   public void updateMoreApp(String appName, String activityName,
           String appPackageName, int index, OnDataBaseUpdateListener listener) {
       appsMoreApps[index].setData(appName, activityName, appPackageName);
       this.mListener = listener;
       new updateDataTask(false, index).execute();
   }

   public void updateDashBoardApp(String appName, String activityName,
           String appPackageName, int index) {
       appsDashBoard[index].setData(appName, activityName, appPackageName);
       new updateDataTask(true, index).execute();
   }

   public void updateDashBoardApp(String appName, String activityName,
           String appPackageName, int index, OnDataBaseUpdateListener listener) {
       appsDashBoard[index].setData(appName, activityName, appPackageName);
       this.mListener = listener;
       new updateDataTask(true, index).execute();
   }

   public void updateAppsFromDatabase() {
       new getDataTask().execute();
   }

   public AppsData[] getDashBoardApps() {
       return appsDashBoard;
   }

   public AppsData[] getMoreApps() {
       return appsMoreApps;
   }

   private void updateAppInDatabase(boolean isDashBoardApp, int index) {
       ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
       cv = new ContentValues();
       if (isDashBoardApp) {
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME,
                   appsDashBoard[index].getPackageName());
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME,
                   appsDashBoard[index].getActivityName());
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME, appsDashBoard[index].getAppName());
       } else {
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME,
                   appsMoreApps[index].getPackageName());
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME,
                   appsMoreApps[index].getActivityName());
           cv.put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME, appsMoreApps[index].getAppName());
       }

       int dbIndex = isDashBoardApp ? index : index + appsDashBoard.length;
       appsProvider.updateApp(cv, dbIndex);

   }

   private int saveDataInDatabase() {
       ContentValues[] cv = new ContentValues[appsDashBoard.length
               + appsMoreApps.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < appsDashBoard.length; i++) {
           cv[i] = new ContentValues();
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_ID, appsDashBoard[i].getId());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME,
                   appsDashBoard[i].getPackageName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME,
                   appsDashBoard[i].getActivityName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME, appsDashBoard[i].getAppName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_IS_FROM_DASHBOARD, "1");
       }

       for (int i = appsDashBoard.length; i < (appsMoreApps.length + appsDashBoard.length); i++) {
           cv[i] = new ContentValues();
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_ID, appsMoreApps[i
                   - appsDashBoard.length].getId());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME, appsMoreApps[i
                   - appsDashBoard.length].getPackageName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME, appsMoreApps[i
                   - appsDashBoard.length].getActivityName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME, appsMoreApps[i
                   - appsDashBoard.length].getAppName());
           cv[i].put(AppsTable.COLUMN_IS_FROM_DASHBOARD, "0");
       }
       return appsProvider.insertBulkApps(cv);
   }

   private void getDataFromDatabase() {

       Cursor appCursor = appsProvider.getAllApps();
       appCursor.moveToFirst();

       for (int i = 0; i < appsDashBoard.length; i++) {
           appsDashBoard[i]
                   .setData(
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME)),
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME)),
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME)));
           appCursor.moveToNext();
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < appsMoreApps.length; i++) {
           appsMoreApps[i]
                   .setData(
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_NAME)),
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_ACTIVITY_NAME)),
                           appCursor.getString(appCursor
                                   .getColumnIndex(AppsTable.COLUMN_APP_PACKAGE_NAME)));
           appCursor.moveToNext();
       }
   }

   private class saveDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

       @Override
       protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
           return saveDataInDatabase();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

           if (mListener != null)
               mListener.onDataUpdate(TYPE_SAVE);
           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }

   }

   private class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           getDataFromDatabase();
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           if (mListener != null)
               mListener.onDataUpdate(TYPE_GET);
           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }

   private class updateDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       boolean isFromDashBoard;
       int index;

       public updateDataTask(boolean isFromDashBoard, int index) {
           this.isFromDashBoard = isFromDashBoard;
           this.index = index;

       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           updateAppInDatabase(isFromDashBoard, index);
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           if (mListener != null)
               mListener.onDataUpdate(TYPE_UPDATE);
           super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }

   public static class AppsData {
       int id;
       String appName;
       String activityName;
       String packageName;

       public AppsData(int id, String appName, String activityName,
               String packageName) {
           this.id = id;
           this.appName = appName;
           this.activityName = activityName;
           this.packageName = packageName;
       }

       public void setData(String appName, String activityName,
               String packageName) {
           this.appName = appName;
           this.activityName = activityName;
           this.packageName = packageName;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public String getAppName() {
           return appName;
       }

       public String getPackageName() {
           return packageName;
       }

       public String getActivityName() {
           return activityName;
       }
   }

   public interface OnDataBaseUpdateListener {
       public void onDataUpdate(int updateType);
   } 
   }
   ```

It helps you in creating a more structured code and always available data, just need to call `AppsHelper.getInstance(context)` and boom!!!. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save them when user closes the application , you must save them in shared preferences or database or in a file in phone memory!
and for inside application, you can simply define them in a class that extends from `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and pass them between activities/fragments/etc